# Flutter: How to Stop Playing Sound

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Button1 that plays the sounds. (Code Below)

```
AudioPlayer cache;
AudioPlayer player;
    
void _playFile(String yol) async {
     print(yol);
     AudioCache player = AudioCache();                                                         
     player.play('bird1.mp3'); // assign player here
}
```

And the other button(BUTTON2) must stop the sound. When I press BUTTON1, sound start playing. But even I go previously page sound still playing.

Button2 execute this code:

```
void cancelPlay() {
   print("stop");
   player.pause();
}
```

And the error is:

```
The method 'pause' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: pause()
```

Comment: it depends on where you're calling that method, because the error you have is because the player variable is probably out of scope and evaluating to null

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your player in main scope. It won't be accessible if you initialize it in your playFile method.

```
AudioPlayer cache; // You need to initialize it too!

AudioCache player = AudioCache(); // Here, we initialized the player.                                                         


void _playFile(String yol) async {
     print(yol);
     player.play('bird1.mp3'); // assign player here
}

void cancelPlay() {
   print("stop");
   player.pause();
}
```

Comment: Now it says:  player (cache) has no method "pause"  :(